# How to detect whether the websocket connection is normal?

Tags: java-websocket

I use the springboot framework to regularly check if the websocket is unblocked with a timer. I call the isOpen function and find that when the client disconnects and the websocket is disconnected, the server's call to isOpen remains true. When I try to send a message, no exception is thrown. How can I determine if the connection is disconnected in this case.

[image]

Timely detection of user disconnection.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.